# Is there any possible way to add a tap on right to go forward and tap on left to go backward like Instagram stories in flutter Pageview?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector, pageviews, flutter-pageview

Expected implementation of the question is similar to Instagram stories. There exists a package called story_view in flutter which does the same but it's not possible to add a Pageview as child as per my understanding. So, any way this can be implemented in flutter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `GestureDetector` and `PageController` on your page view to achieve this. Where `GestureDetector` is used to get the tapped position of the screen and to call the page controller to go forward or backwards depending on that position.

Wrap `PageView(controller: _pageController,...)` with `GestureDetector` and then define `onTapDown` something like the below:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    final x = localOffset.dx;

    // if x is less than halfway across the screen and user is not on first page 
    if(x < box.size.width / 2){
      //   _pageController.previousPage(...)
    }else{
      // Assume the user tapped on the other half of the screen and check they are not on the last page
      //  _pageController.nextPage(...)
    }

  },
  child: PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    ...
  )
)
```

As you can see I haven't fully implemented a solution but this should be what you want

Comment: Thank you so much will try this on my code. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: No problem I hope it helps! You might also need to check that `_pageController` has attached to the page view before doing previous/next page. You can check this with `_pageController.hasClients`

Comment: i wonder how can i write step definition for this feature. Is there any way to make flutter world driver to tap on these specific areas ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know enough about flutter world driver to help. In terms of steps displayed to the user you could a package like https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview